# Plot with d3.js in Google Apps Script and embed plot in Google Sheet, Google Sites and Google Slides

Tags: d3.js, google-sheets, google-visualization, google-slides

I am using Google Sheets to create some plots from the data and then I export those plots as iframes and embed them into Google Sites and Google Slides.

I was wondering if I can do the same using D3 instead of Google Charts. 
So, my main goal is to generate the plot with D3 in Google Apps scripts and then view this plot in Google sheet (as the same as a Google Chart plot).
After that, I would like to export this plot into Google WebSites and/or Google Slides.

Is it possible?

Comment: Can you provide your sample script of `generate the plot with D3 in Google Apps scripts`? Of course, please remove your personal information.